# Modifying TFS Work Items through TFS Database

Tags: database, tfs, tfs-workitem

Is there a way to update work items through the TFS database? I am asking this because my task is to do a mass data transfer from a customized TFS Priority Field "DefectTracking_InternalPriority" to the default "Microsoft_VSTS_Common_Priority" priority field. I cannot do it through excel as there are several thousand work items that need to be updated appropriately.

As of now, I am thinking of making a simply SQL script and run it against the dbo.DimWorkItem table under the TFS_Warehouse database to update the priority of these work items. Would this be the correct solution for my issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The first rule of TFS is "don't mess with the database!" :-)

If you don't want to use Excel try writing a small console program that uses the TFS API. There's plenty of sample code out there that can show you how to query for the work items you are interested in, and also how to update them.

To get you started, here's an MSDN document describing [how to update a work item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb130323.aspx) via the API